# Foreach loop working differently inside using block, than outside?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to finish a project in C# and I would like to know why these two codes behave differently.

I'm trying to populate a database with values from a string.
The first version of my code works, but the second one doesn't.

```
foreach (var Line in Lines)
{
    string[] SplittedLine = Line.Split(Spliter);

    using (SqlCeConnection Connection = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        Connection.Open();
        SqlCeCommand Command = new SqlCeCommand(
          @"INSERT INTO Localitati(Nume) VALUES (@Nume)", 
            Connection);

        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Nume", SplittedLine[0]);
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

```
using (var Connection = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    Connection.Open();

    foreach (var Line in Lines)
    {
        string[] SplittedLine = Line.Split(Spliter);
        MessageBox.Show(SplittedLine[0]);
        var Command = new SqlCeCommand(
          @"INSERT INTO Localitati(Nume) VALUES (@Nume)", 
            Connection);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Nume", SplittedLine[0]);
    }

}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What's wrong with the second one?

Comment: A good way to troubleshoot would have been to just copy and paste the exact same code into the two different scenarios, your code varies between the two, so you really cant assume it is because of the `using`

Comment: the second code is missing Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot `Command.ExecuteNonQuery();` in the second variant.
So the operation is never submitted to the database.

Answer (score 0):

When executing query in a *loop*, try to keep it as short as possible: move all declarations out of the loop and leave there parameters aggignments and query execution

**Code:**

```
using (var Connection = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString)) {
  Connection.Open();

  string sql = 
     @"INSERT INTO Localitati(Nume) 
            VALUES (@Nume)";

  using (SqlCeCommand Command = new SqlCeCommand(sql, Connection)) {
    Command.Parameters.Add("@Nume", SqlDbType.VarChar); //TODO: provide RDBMS type here

    foreach (var Line in Lines) {
      // Assign parameter(s)...
      Command.Parameters["@Nume"].Value = Line.Substring(0, Line.IndexOf(Spliter));
      // ... and execute query
      Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }   
  }
}
```